# How to build and loop through a group of expressions referencing environment objects (without list structure)? [R]

Tags: r, lapply, purrr, rlang

I want to simplify the below in functional form:

```
  write_file(s01e01, 's01e01.txt')
  write_file(s01e02, 's01e02.txt')
  write_file(s01e03, 's01e03.txt')
  write_file(s02e01, 's01e01.txt') ...
```

These character objects `s01e01` and the like, all exist in my global environment named `s[01-05]e[01-03]`. I know I could just put them all into a list and write them to files with `*apply` or `purrr` functions, but is there a way to refer to all of their bare names, inside a function, using a specified string pattern instead?

I know I can get the filename strings I want by 
using

```
names <- c('s01e01', 's01e02', 's01e03', ... , 's05e03')
files <- paste(names, 'txt', sep = '.')
```

So how would I construct a function along the lines of

```
write_txt_files <- function(names) {
 files <- paste(names, 'txt', sep = '.'))

 # 15 variables from s01e01 to s05e03
 c1 <- c('01', '02', '03', '04', '05')
 c2 <- c('01', '02', '03')
 varnames <- paste0(paste0('s', c1), rep(paste0('e', c2), 5)) %>% sort
 vectorized_write_file(convertStringToExpr(varnames), files)
                       # ^bare object                 ^strings
}
```

Comment: You're right, definitely better to implement it via a list instead, but thanks for tuning me to `get()` that's exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get()` in place of your `convertStringToExpr()` function. That will get the value of a variable with the name of the string you pass to it. But keep in mind that having all these different variables in your global namespace isn't a good practice. If you had kept all these objects in a (named) list, it would be much easier to work with. That's the R-way at least.